# problem in matching line using while loop in bash

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, syntax, pattern-matching

I have two files

file1

> ```
> K00940
> K02183
> K03781
> K13413
> K13414
> K13424
> K13425
> K13449
> K14496
> K14497
> K14498
> K14509
> K14510
> K14512
> K17686
> K20535
> K20557
> K20600
> K20603
> K20606
> K20607
> K20716
> K20718
> K20726
> ```

and

file2

```
  K00940 ndk; nucleoside-diphosphate kinase [EC:2.7.4.6]
            K02183 CALM; calmodulin
            K03781 katE; catalase [EC:1.11.1.6]
            K13413 MKK4_5; mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase 4/5 [EC:2.7.12.2]
            K13414 MEKK1; mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase kinase 1 [EC:2.7.11.25]
            K13424 WRKY33; WRKY transcription factor 33
            K13425 WRKY22; WRKY transcription factor 22
            K13449 PR1; pathogenesis-related protein 1
```

I am using the following script to match the first file with the second  file

```
cat file1 |while read line;do grep $line file2 >>file3 done
```

but it is not working file3 is empty.
can anyone help regarding this matter?

Comment: Is `grep -Ff file1 file2 > file3` what you're looking for?

Comment: Also, after adding the missing semicolon, your code snippet works fine, if not very efficiently.

Comment: Insert `;` before `done`.

Comment: @Shawn it's not working well, the second file contains multiple time  `K` number, `grep -Ff` will print the only first match

Comment: @DrAnimo use that *instead* of your while loop.

Comment: @Shawn I have try but it is printing only first entry.

Comment: I assure you that running `grep -Ff file1 file2` with the example files you have in your question prints more than one line.

Answer (score 0):

The comment is correct or you could use `fgrep -f file1 file2 > file3`

The `-f` enables you to specify a file for the patterns separated by newline characters, so read the lines of `file1` for matching lines in `file2`

UPDATE: Now that I read a bit, you don't even need `fgrep` or the `-F` switch for grep. `grep -f file1 file2 > file3` will do just fine.

Comment: If the comment is *correct* let its owner make an answer out of it.

Comment: `grep -F` (Prefer that over the long-obsolete `fgrep` alias) matches fixed strings instead of regular expressions (And matches multiple ones very efficiently). Unless you're actually using regular expressions, prefer it over plain `grep` or `grep -E`.

Comment: @oguzismail I'm not sure what you mean here, this is literally my first answer :) Should I tag the commenter in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may also use the `comm` command. See `man comm` for more details, but you may just `comm -1 file1 file2`. This will work however only on sorted files.